# diagram of a double p-trap for a double kitchen sink

Tags: kitchens, sink

have a double sink in my kitchen and the water run back and into the empty sink. can I put a double p-trap in and will it stop the back rain

Comment: Is the drain plugged somewhere downstream? Tried cleaning it out (a snake)? When & how does the water run back into the empty sink?

Comment: when I used the sink to wash something in and fill the one sink and release the water it goes to the other sink and then drains very slow.  inch and half pvc would going to a 2" solve the problem .  in the bath room sinks it drains have two sinks but have separate drain lines where the kitchen both sinks go to the same line.

Answer (score 2):

A separate trap won't solve this problem when the water backs up through the trap it will do the same thing. The trap is there to stop sewer gas from entering the home.

Comment: what is the answer to stop the water from backing up in my sink  water is very slow draining Is the size to the pipe that the water drain from not big enough. has inch and half pvc for the drain would 2" make it better

Comment: Whithout a photo I would say possibly, a plugged drain or vent can also cause problems. I have seen some wild plumbing jobs on double sinks. A photo of the plumbing may give us a clue if it's not the drain or vent.